# Django Custom filter "a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING"

Tags: django, django-queryset

I wrote a custom filter, linked to a MultipleChoiceFilter with 5 choices (0,1,1.75,2.5,3.25 and 4) :

```
 def filtre_personnalise(self,queryset, name,value):
        query=FicheIdentification.objects.none()
        for i in value:
            if i=='0':
                query|=queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('entreprise',Entreprise.objects.all())).exclude(pk__in=[x.entreprise.siret for x in EvaluationGenerale.objects.all()])
            else :
                query|=queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('entreprise',Entreprise.objects.all())).annotate(note_moyenne=Avg('entreprise__evaluationgenerale__note')).filter(note_moyenne__range=(float(i),float(i)+0.75))
        return query
```

If I tick each value individually everything works as expected, the returned queryset is what I want it to be.

Everything also works fine if I tick several values simultaneously as long as 0 is not one of them (eg. 1 and 4 work fine together).

But as soon as 0 is ticked with another value I get the following error :

```
a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING
```

I honestly have no idea on why it behaves this way. I tried to replace `|` by `.union` but got this error :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
```

I think this one is related to the use of `.annotate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing `.annotate` by `.alias` to avoid creating a new column. Then I joined the queries with `.union` instead of `|`.